# AWS EC2 user data not working using Java API

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have following code to create `EC2` instance with user data ...

But it not creates log file after creating `EC2` instance.

Plz help me if i have did anything wrong..

The code is below.:-

```
class EC2Demo{
<br>public static void main(String str[]){

{  //AWS Credencial lines......

        RunInstancesRequest request = new RunInstancesRequest();
        request.setInstanceType(InstanceType.T1Micro);
        request.setMinCount(1); 
        request.setMaxCount(1);
        request.setImageId("ami-ab844dc2");
        request.setKeyName("VIIT1");
        ArrayList<String> securityGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
        securityGroups.add("VIITgroup");
        request.setSecurityGroups(securityGroups);
        Placement placement=new Placement();
        placement.setAvailabilityZone("us-east-1d");
        request.setPlacement(placement);

        request.setUserData(getUserDataScript());
        System.out.println("Shell Script");
        System.out.println("-------->>>>"+ec2.runInstances(request));
        //}
        System.out.println("End");

    }
    private static String getUserDataScript(){
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        lines.add("#! /bin/bash");
        lines.add("cd /home");
        lines.add("echo `ls` >> /home/test.log");
        //lines.add("shutdown -h 0");
        String str = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(join(lines, "\n").getBytes()));

        return str;
    }

    static String join(Collection<String> s, String delimiter) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<String> iter = s.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            builder.append(iter.next());
            if (!iter.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
            builder.append(delimiter);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the AMI you are using support cloud init?

Comment: I am using amazon linux ami.

Dont know how to check it.

Plz you can suggest any supporting amazon linux ami list.?

Comment: This ami `ami-ab844dc2` is not an amazon linux ami. Instead its SUSE. As far as I know it does not support cloud init. Try it again with ami `ami-c02ab6a9`.